# Ubuntu16.04 htacess not working properly for the pages which have same name as its URL php

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I am using below code to route every page through index.php

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Using this code to route every page through index.php ie. 
**http://example.com/index.php?page=product**.

This is working for the pages which have different name than its url but not working for the pages which have same name and same url 

**e.g** I have a page aboutus.php and in url http://example.com/aboutus then it is giving "404 not found" but when we have some url like http://example.com/userlogin and page name is login.php is working fine.
Only facing issue with for the pages which have same url as its name.

Comment: Did you try to set the option `-MultiViews` for your virtual host?

Comment: @syscall 
Below is the virtual host part.

`<Directory /var/www/html>  
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
        AllowOverride All  
        Options +Indexes  
</Directory>`

Comment: Try to set `-MultiViews` instead of `MultiViews`.

Comment: @syscall Can you provide me the complete code for virtual host. I am setting it to  -MultiViews  but after that apache is not restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `MultiViews` option :

```
<Directory /var/www/html> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
</Directory>
```

NB: @RanjeetSingh Solves the issues my removing `MultiViews` (See comments below).

Comment: I have removed MultiViews  and its working , thanks @syscall

Comment: @RanjeetSingh You have removed the "word" MultiViews or used `-` sign?

Comment: I have removed word MultiViews

Comment: @RanjeetSingh Thank you. I'll add this to the answer, for future readers.